# How to define interface for object's every field must be instance of an other interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, oop, interface

I have this TypeScript interface definition:

```js
interface FieldInterface {
  label: string;
  placeholder: string;
  title: string;
}
```

I have this data structure in first model:

```js
fields = {
  name: {
    label: '...',
    placeholder: '...',
    title: '...'
  },
  age: {
    label: '...',
    placeholder: '...',
    title: '...'
  },
  birth_place: {
    label: '...',
    placeholder: '...',
    title: '...'
  }
};
```

I have this data structure in second model:

```js
fields = {
  city: {
    label: '...',
    placeholder: '...',
    title: '...'
  },
  zip: {
    label: '...',
    placeholder: '...',
    title: '...'
  },
  street_address: {
    label: '...',
    placeholder: '...',
    title: '...'
  },
  house_number: {
    label: '...',
    placeholder: '...',
    title: '...'
  }
};
```

Can I say something like this somehow, like this?:

```js
interface FieldContainerInterface {
  *: FieldInterface;
}
```

I want to say in interface all proerties must be an instace of `FieldInterface`.

Can I do somehow?

Comment: `Record<string, FieldInterface>` could be the type you use. Also take a look at [indexable types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)

Comment: @apokryfos could you explaint this with an example code please?

Comment: `const fields : Record<string, FieldInterface> = { .... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [indexable-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) (as mentioned in comment above)

```js
interface FieldInterface {
  label: string;
  placeholder: string;
  title: string;
}

interface FieldContainerInterface {
  [key: string]: FieldInterface;
}

const fields: FieldContainerInterface = {
  name: {
    label: '...',
    placeholder: '...',
    title: '...'
  },
  age: {
    label: '...',
    placeholder: '...',
    title: '...'
  },
  birth_place: {
    label: '...',
    placeholder: '...',
    title: '...'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the indexable types, Typescript defines a set of *utility types*. One of them is the `Record<K, T>` which is what you need.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt

```
type FieldContainerInterface = Record<string, FieldInterface>
```